# Numpy matrix determinant precision problems

Tags: python, numpy, algebra

I am trying to write a script on python to determine a matrix determinant using Gauss method. It works correctly, but the precision isn't enough for me.
My code is:

```
import scipy.linalg as sla
import numpy as np
def my_det(X):
    n = len(X)
    s = 0
    if n != len(X[0]):
        return ValueError
    for i in range(0, n):
        maxElement = abs(X[i][i])
        maxRow = i
        for k in range(i+1, n):
            if abs(X[k][i]) > maxElement:
                maxElement = abs(X[k][i])
                maxRow = k
        if maxRow != i:
            s += 1
        for k in range(i, n):
            X[i][k], X[maxRow][k] = X[maxRow][k], X[i][k]
        for k in range(i+1, n):
            c = -X[k][i]/X[i][i]
            for j in range(i, n):
                if i == j:
                    X[k][j] = 0
                else:
                    X[k][j] += c * X[i][j]
    det = (-1)**s
    for i in range(n):
        det *= X[i][i]
    return det
```

And I have tests for this code:

```
for x in range(10):
X = np.random.rand(3,3)
if np.abs(my_det(X) - sla.det(X)) > 1e-6:
    print('FAILED')
```

My function fails all tests. I tried Decimals, but it didn't help.
What's wrong?

Comment: what is `sla` ?

Comment: import scipy.linalg as sla

Comment: sla.det is based on LAPACK routine which is linear algebra routine in C. It seems to be that python is not precise as C

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code fails the test condition, `abs(my_det(X) -
sla.det(X)) < 1e-6`, is not due to lack of precision but rather the change
in sign brought about the unintended side-effect of `my_det` mutating `X`:

```
X[i][k], X[maxRow][k] = X[maxRow][k], X[i][k]
```

This row swapping changes the sign of the determinant.
The code uses `s` to adjust for the change in sign, but `X` itself is altered
in a way which changes the sign of the determinant.

So the `X` passed to `my_det` is not the same as the `X` which is subsequently passed to `sla.det`. Here is an example where the alteration of `X` changes the sign of the determinant:

```
In [55]: X = np.random.rand(3, 3); X
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0.38062719,  0.41892961,  0.88277747],
       [ 0.39881724,  0.00188804,  0.79258322],
       [ 0.40195279,  0.3950311 ,  0.32771527]])

In [56]: my_det(X)
Out[56]: 0.098180005266934267

In [57]: X
Out[57]: 
array([[ 0.40195279,  0.3950311 ,  0.32771527],
       [ 0.        , -0.39006151,  0.46742438],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.62620267]])

In [58]: sla.det(X)
Out[58]: -0.09818000526693427
```

---

You can fix the problem by making a copy of `X` inside `my_det`:

```
def my_det(X):
    X = np.array(X, copy=True)  # copy=True is the default; shown here for emphasis
    ...
```

Thus, subsequent changes to `X` within `my_det` no longer affect the `X` outside of
`my_det`.

---

```
import scipy.linalg as sla
import numpy as np


def my_det(X):
    X = np.array(X, dtype='float64', copy=True)
    n = len(X)
    s = 0
    if n != len(X[0]):
        return ValueError
    for i in range(0, n):
        maxElement = abs(X[i, i])
        maxRow = i
        for k in range(i + 1, n):
            if abs(X[k, i]) > maxElement:
                maxElement = abs(X[k, i])
                maxRow = k
        if maxRow != i:
            s += 1
        for k in range(i, n):
            X[i, k], X[maxRow, k] = X[maxRow, k], X[i, k]
        for k in range(i + 1, n):
            c = -X[k, i] / X[i, i]
            for j in range(i, n):
                if i == j:
                    X[k, j] = 0
                else:
                    X[k, j] += c * X[i, j]
    det = (-1)**s
    for i in range(n):
        det *= X[i, i]
    return det


for i in range(10):
    X = np.random.rand(3, 3)
    diff = abs(my_det(X) - sla.det(X))
    if diff > 1e-6:
        print('{} FAILED: {:0.8f}'.format(i, diff))
```

---

Also note that dtype matters:

```
In [88]: my_det(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
Out[88]: 6
```

while the correct answer is

```
In [89]: my_det(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3).astype(float))
Out[89]: 0.0
```

Since `my_det` uses division (in `c = -X[k, i] / X[i, i]`), we need `X` to have floating point dtype so that the `/` performs floating point division, not integer division.
So to fix this, use `X = np.asarray(X, dtype='float64')` to ensure that `X` has dtype `float64`:

```
def my_det(X):
    X = np.array(X, dtype='float64', copy=True)
    ...
```

With this change,

```
In [91]: my_det(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
Out[91]: 0.0
```

now gives the correct answer.

Comment: Increasing the matrix shape, e.g. to `70x70`, I get a big difference again. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `numpy.linalg.det` or `scipy.linalg.det` function ?
These function compute the determinant using a LU decomposition and LAPACK. It will be faster than any 'manual' function.

Comment: I know, but I really need to do it on my own

Answer (score -1):

Using numpy will be simpler, even for 3x3 matrices or more:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2,1,4],[4,2,1],[5,1,3]])
print(np.linalg.det(a))
```